# Cucumber 5.1.2 doesn't see any features

Tags: java, cucumber

I was using cucumber version 1.2.5. on my project. And I had the following test runner class that used to work just fine:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = "src/test/resources/feature",
    glue = "product.cucumber.steps",
    tags = {"not @ignore", "@current"})
public class TestRunner {

}
```

But today I attempted to update cucumber to version 5.1.2. And suddenly this runner has stopped working. I get the following error now:

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.cucumber.core.gherkin.vintage.GherkinVintageFeature.(GherkinVintageFeature.java:30)
    at io.cucumber.core.gherkin.vintage.GherkinVintageFeatureParser.parseGherkin5(GherkinVintageFeatureParser.java:31)
    at io.cucumber.core.gherkin.vintage.GherkinVintageFeatureParser.parse(GherkinVintageFeatureParser.java:51)
    at io.cucumber.core.feature.FeatureParser.parseResource(FeatureParser.java:43)
More than that, now all my steps in feature files are shown as undefined. What could be the reason of this? Please help.

UPD: Okay, I figured out what the problem was. I didn't know that I had to change the main class in run configuration to  io.cucumber.core.cli.Main. Now that I've changed it I see that my tests started running again.

Comment: Try with `glue = "steps",` if `steps` is the folder with step definitions.

Answer (score 0):

You ran into https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/1877. Try using v5.1.3.

Comment: No, that's not it. I forgot to change the main class to  io.cucumber.core.cli.Main after updating cucumber. Thanks for trying to help anyway.

Comment: @ Cute Shark can you help me I got the same problem but where to change the main class